# Is my old HP laptop preventing Linux from running smoothly?

Tags: boot, hardware, initramfs, fsck, hp

I have an older HP laptop. I don't know all the specs but I believe it is a G60 notebook with a dual core intel pentium processor. It used to have Windows Vista on it. I don't remember the exact hard drive, but it's more than 250 GB and less than 300.

I've wiped it a few times and put different Linux distros on it. I started small with Puppy, then went to Mint Cinnamon (something in the 19 family) and now I have Ubuntu 20.04.

Each time the installation goes smoothly and I am able to get it setup with the apps and customizations I like. Internet connection is fine, speed is fine, I can ssh into my other machines np. It can go into a sleeplike mode and wake up fine. The issue starts when the system shuts down and has to boot up from being off. Each time, something seems to go wrong. Mostly what happens is it will default to some kind of command line boot, and many times it is the `initramfs`/BusyBox prompt.

9 times out of 10 it tells me something is wrong with `/dev/sda5` or something and to run `fsck` on it. I do, the issue might or might not be solved, then I reboot and sometimes it makes it to the desktop, other times it's this cycle above over and over again. With Ubuntu the stage I am at is booting to the desktop and being able to use the mouse, but the desktop is unresponsive to clicks, keyboard shortcuts, etc. It keeps refreshing and positions the mouse in the default lower right hand corner.

I don't believe there is a fundamental issue with the hardware of my machine. But after looking at some different forums I've seen mention of the boot process being thwarted depending on the hardware of the machine.

I know I'm using an old machine and that 20.04 is newer, but so far the comp has been more than able to run whatever I want. I keep going bigger and it keeps doing fine. It's the boot process where I hit a snag. I am by *no* means a super OS-savvy guy. I'm a hobbyist with less than a year of Linux exp. I just follow directions. I just say that to say if you think you may know what's going on, please, explain me like I'm 5 :)

Comment: There might be a fundamental issue with your harddisk.  Try working with a live CD to rule that out.

Comment: How much RAM? You may do better with a lightweight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie  I was able to install kubuntu which is more of a middleweight flavor on my old 2006 dual core system with 1.5GB RAM. Not speedy (it never was), but functional. But that was more of a test install just to see if it works. System batteries all all dead and it only runs from mains.